# How do I obtain a court order to receive a certified death certificate of custodial parent to terminate income withholding order in Arizona?

Tags: arizona, child-support

According to the Maricopa county Arizona vital records, I cannot request a certified death certificate since I am not a family member (we were never married) or have a court order. I am needing to cancel income withholding payments to the clearinghouse since I have taken natural custody as we had joint-custody. The petition to terminate income withholding order says I need a copy of the death certificate. What should I do?

Comment: Could a family member request a copy for you?

Comment: Possibly, but we don't exactly have a good relationship. I was trying to see if there are alternatives.

Comment: Your child is presumably a family member - they can request it

Comment: Says the person has to be 18 unfortunately. Our kid is 13.

Answer (score 1):

Issue a subpoena to the vital statistics department that keeps the death certificates to obtain the death certificate in a civil action. This could be in a continuation of the action that established to obligation to withhold, or in a separate action support by an affidavit and ideally, an obituary or other third party source, tending to show that the person is dead.